# How to avoid using limit clause in my redshift query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a below query where I am using `limit 8` to get value of dates as shown below:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column
FROM dimensions.customer LIMIT 8
```

Below is the output I get from above query:

```
2021-01-10
2021-01-03
2020-12-27
2020-12-20
2020-12-13
2020-12-06
2020-11-29
2020-11-22
```

Is there any way to avoid using `limit 8` in my above query and still get same output? One of our platform doesn't allow us to run queries if it has limit in it so trying to see if I can rewrite it differently in sql redshift?

Below is my full query where I am using my `dates` CTE:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column
    FROM dimensions.customer LIMIT 8
)
SELECT 
dates.week_column, 
'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_column + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number,
COUNT(DISTINCT features.client_id) AS total
FROM dimensions.program features 
JOIN dates ON features.last_update <= dates.week_column
WHERE features.type = 'capacity'
AND features.status = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_column
ORDER by dates.week_column DESC
```

How can I rewrite my `dates` CTE query differently so that it can give me same output?

**Update**

If I run query like this it gives me an error but if I run innermost sql query inside `from` then it gives me data.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
      FROM dimensions.customer
     ) c
WHERE seqnum <= 8;
```

Error is:

```
Invalid operation: Output timestamp out of range after subtracting constant. Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Output timestamp out of range after subtracting constant.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT . . .   -- whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
      FROM dimensions.customer
     ) c
WHERE seqnum <= 8;
```

In Redshift, the `ORDER BY` is optional for `ROW_NUMBER()`.  In general, I would encourage you to have an `ORDER BY`.  That is true of your query as well.  `LIMIT` is normally used with an `ORDER BY`.

EDIT:

The idea is the same:

```
with dates as (
     ),
     q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (order by weeks_column desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum <= 8;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I was updating my question with my full query where I am using my `dates` CTE while your answer came in. How can I use your suggestion in my original query?

Comment: btw I am getting an error  after running your suggestion as it is as `error: Output timestamp out of range after subtracting constant. code:`. Any thoughts what could be wrong?

Comment: @AndyP . . . Just use `row_number()` in your CTE to calculate `seqnum`, so you can filter instead of using `limit`.

Comment: I updated my question with what I have tried. It is giving me an error when I am running it unless I am doing it wrong. Can you provide an example basis on my query?

Comment: Any thoughts on why my updated query in the question gives an error? I saw your edit but its almost same as the query in the updated section which gives an error so wanted to see what could be wrong in that?

Comment: @AndyP . . . Remove the `order by` from any subqueries or CTEs.